# Как проверить число на чётность в python

Tags: python

Я пробовал и

```
number = int(input("Введите число, а программа определит чётное ли оно: "))

if number % 2:
    print("Это чётное число")
else:
    print("Это НЕчётное число")
```

и

```
number = int(input("Введите число, а программа определит чётное ли оно: "))

if number = int:
    print("Это чётное число")
else:
    print("Это НЕчётное число")
```

В любом случае выдаёт не точный результат.

Comment: `number % 2 == 0`... забыли сравнить с нулем. Ведь если остача будет равна не 0, то число явно нечетное.

Comment: "В любом случае выдаёт не точный результат." - расшифруйте, в теле вопроса, (кнопка "править")

Answer (score 3):

```
number = int(input("Введите число, а программа определит чётное ли оно: "))

if number % 2 == 0:
    print("Это чётное число")
else:
    print("Это НЕчётное число")
```

Число считается четным, если делится на 2 без остатка. Другими словами, если остаток от деления на 2 равен нулю: `number % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 3):

Просто поменяйте местами print-ы:

```py
number = int(input("Введите число, а программа определит чётное ли оно: "))

if number % 2:
    print("Это НЕчётное число")
else:
    print("Это чётное число")
```